# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 .NET Manifest Resource Corruption?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, text-files, embedded-resource

**Problem**

I've got some simple code which extracted a text from a resource file. This previously worked on Visual Studio 2015 but seems to fail on Visual Studio Update 1. The failure manifests itself as a string which appears to have characters missing in parts and the texts spliced together with "..." in between the legible parts.

I've checked the byte code analysis of the file which confirms it is UTF8. Even when saved and consumed as ASCII/ANSI and individually read character by character, it yields no invalid or unexpected ASCII codes, confirming the source text file encoding is not the issue.

Note: My resource is in a common DLL, hence the convoluted extraction using GetType(). I can't show you the file for commercial reasons, but it *currently* appears particular to this file.

```
using (Stream stream = server.GetType().Module.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream( scriptResourceName ) )
{
    if (stream == null)
        throw new Exception("Unable to find the script file");

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        strScript = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest what might be going on as I'm at a lose end?

**Update**

Using VS2015 without update 1 fixes the issue.
Using VS2015 update 2 fixes the issue.

Was this a known issue with the resource compiler in Update 1? - I couldn't find any reference to it. It's worrying to say the least.

Comment: Assuming the file is embedded during the build. It might be interesting to try doing a `diff` on the two text files in different versions to see, possibly even trying to view a binary representation to see if something has changed slightly in the header (encoding) or the file contents (corruption I guess)

Comment: The original text file is exactly the same between builds, and exactly the version in TFS. I just install/uninstall updates and run the automated test to prove it. The binary diff might yield some more detail. Thx.